# Multipart, spring-boot and JBoss - Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, multipart

I have an application that uses **spring-boot** and embedded **Tomcat** for development, and on production server it is deployed on **JBoss 6.4 EAP**.
After adding support for JBoss, multipart file upload stopped working. On both containers it was throwing **MissingServletRequestPartException**.

Adding *MultipartConfigElement* to *ServletRegistrationBean* fixed this issue on tomcat, but for JBoss it's still not working. Do you have any ideas where is the problem?

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet, MultipartConfigElement
        multipartConfig) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    registration.getUrlMappings().clear();
    registration.addUrlMappings("/*");
    registration.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfig);
    return registration;
}
```

Endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public SomeResponse uploadFileWithComment(
    @RequestParam(value = "file") final MultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam(value = "comment") String comment) {
    ...
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rebelek.Application</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If you are actually using Spring Boot then why do you use a `web.xml`? Basically you are using a different config for development and production right now. Also if you really need this you would need the Spring Boot Legacy stuff to properly bootstrap things.

Comment: Without web.xml application is not deployed correctly to jboss even though main class extends SpringBootServletInitializer with configure method override, have @SpringBootApplication annotation and <start-class> is set in pom.xml. After finished deployment endpoints are not detected and each url gives me 404. But I'm not giving up, still trying to make it consistent.

Comment: As stated if you use a web.xml use the Spring Boot Legacy project for bootstrapping. You have different configurations for dev and prod you are bootstrapping NOT spring boot which basically disables everything.

Comment: After removing web.xml, and adding missing entries in servlet initializers onStartup() problem is solved. Thank you both for good direction.

Comment: @Rebelek consider adding that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

discussed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2958 suggests if you are using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` then you need to do the following as because the springboot autoconfig causes issue:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})
```

define the following beans

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver") 
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver(){ 
CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver(); resolver.setMaxUploadSize(50*1024*1024); return resolver ; 
}


@Bean @Order(0) public MultipartFilter multipartFilter()
{ 
MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter(); 
multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver"); 
return multipartFilter; 
}
```